# Is it possible to rotate two textures on the same object in opposite directions using the same Empty?

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to animate a texture on an object. I've got the material set up on the object, and the node setup uses the Texture Coordinate node with an Empty plugged into the vector socket of the texture (and then into a Color Ramp, but that's not really important) so that when I rotate the Empty, the texture rotates. That works perfectly.

What I'd like to do is essentially duplicate that setup, and use a Mix Shader node to combine them, but have it so that the second instance rotates in the opposite direction.

[image]

So if I rotate the Empty 90 degrees X, Texture 1 will rotate 90 degrees X but Texture 2 will rotate -90 degrees X.  I know I could just create a second Empty and use that and then animate them separately, but I'm trying to avoid that, and it just seems like it should be possible to do this.

Anyway, I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm confused. Is this your node setup with both textures already? And you want to drive the bottom one in the opposite direction? Why is one "object" and the other "generated"? I think you're right, and it shouldn't be hard to accomplish, once I figure out what "it" is. :)

Comment: Is the use of an empty a requirement or would a node-only solution be fine as well?

Comment: Yes, this is the node setup, but they should both be "object." Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: A node solution would also work, but I was really hoping to find an Empty solution because it'll make it easier to animate later on.

Comment: That's alright. Is it only supposed to rotate around the x-axis?

Comment: I was hoping to use random rotation on any axis.

Comment: This is more challenging than I thought it would be... What exactly comes out of the "object" node?

Comment: I'm beginning to think it's just not possible. The Texture mapping maps the texture to the coordinates, in this case the empty. I broke down the vector into XYZ inverted the numbers, and plugged them back into the vector socket of the texture and it did invert the texture, but rotating the empty still causes the texture to rotate in the same direction regardless.

Comment: A second, hidden empty with a driver/constraint might be the way to go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much fiddling with nodes and materials, I couldn't get the direction of rotation to change. What I ended up doing was creating an empty and adding inverted copy rotation and child of... constraints as shows below. The primary control is "CTRL_TextureRotation" and then the material is setup as you have shown, with one texture coordinate driven by the empty and the other by the controller.

[image: Texture Rotation Empty]

Comment: Yes! This worked perfectly! Thank you. I was so focused on trying to figure out a node solution so that I only had to animate one empty that I didn't even think of this. Thank you so much!